# Getting error on foo.Start() when using Task.WhenAll for multiple tasks

Tags: c#, .net, task

I'm getting this error "Start may not be called on a promise-style task." so I commented out the `.Start()`.  I tried again & got this error "Start may not be called on a task that has completed."  So what am I suppose to do to make this work properly?

```
                var dashboardDailyAgeAnalysis = DailyAgeAnalysesTotalRowsCountAsync(v.BookItOutAccountId, v.ClientMgntAccountNumber, yesterdayDate);
                var dashboardDailyBalance = DailyBalanceTotalRowsCountAsync(v.BookItOutAccountId, v.ClientMgntAccountNumber, yesterdayDate);
                var dashboardDailyInventory = DailyInventoryTotalRowsCountAsync(v.BookItOutAccountId, v.ClientMgntAccountNumber, yesterdayDate);

               // dashboardDailyAgeAnalysis.Start();
               // dashboardDailyBalance.Start();
               // dashboardDailyInventory.Start();

                await Task.WhenAll(
                    dashboardDailyAgeAnalysis, dashboardDailyBalance, dashboardDailyInventory
                );

                // Do something with these results.
                var result1 = dashboardDailyAgeAnalysis.Result;
                var result2 = dashboardDailyBalance.Result;
                var result3 = dashboardDailyInventory.Result;
```

Comment: [Don't call `Task.Start`. Ever.](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/02/a-tour-of-task-part-8-starting.html)

Comment: @StephenCleary - I didn't write this code, it was left in there for years.  We just ran into this error while migrating a bit over 20 products & services to new servers.  For some reasons, it work on older server & we're not aware of it, I haven't seen this one before.

Comment: If the code ever worked, it was due to a bug in the .NET Framework. That code was never *supposed* to work. Good luck with the rest of your migration!

Comment: @StephenCleary - Ah so that explain it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        await Task.WhenAll(
            dashboardDailyAgeAnalysis, dashboardDailyBalance, dashboardDailyInventory
        );

        // Do something with these results.
        var result1 = await dashboardDailyAgeAnalysis;
        var result2 = await dashboardDailyBalance;
        var result3 = await dashboardDailyInventory;
```

Comment: Why `Task.WhenAll`? It's doing nothing.

Comment: You sure? It doesn't await until all 3 tasks run parallel and complete before continuing on?

Comment: And @Guillaume Sasdy is spot on about the disadvantages of 3 consecutive awaits

Comment: yes, Guillaume raises a good point about exception handling, but the `Task.WhenAll` in your answer is redundant.

Comment: @Johnathan Barclay it's not redundant, Task.WhenAll and 3 consecutive awaits do not do the same thing in the same way.

Comment: so what is it doing in your example? It returns nothing, and you are not catching exceptions.

Comment: @Johnathan Barclay sorry its not a full fleshed out and tested solution for you, its an answer to the question at hand

Comment: its misleading. As the accepted answer, it appears as though `Task.WhenAll` is required, and might confuse others. It isn't; if you remove it you would observe exactly the same behavior. If you need to catch exceptions, the use of `Task.WhenAll` is appropriate, but this should be explained.

Comment: @ its not required but it is better. The behavior is not exactly the same. I am not interested in continuing this debate with you.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your 3 methods return `Task<int>` you can keep your initial solution to use `Task.WhenAll` like:

```
int[] results = await Task.WhenAll(
    DailyAgeAnalysesTotalRowsCountAsync(v.BookItOutAccountId, v.ClientMgntAccountNumber, yesterdayDate),
    DailyBalanceTotalRowsCountAsync(v.BookItOutAccountId, v.ClientMgntAccountNumber, yesterdayDate),
    DailyInventoryTotalRowsCountAsync(v.BookItOutAccountId, v.ClientMgntAccountNumber, yesterdayDate)
);
```

**With `Task.WhenAll`, you are sure to wait all the tasks are completed, even if one has thrown an exception**. Thus you can use a single try/catch block. If multiple tasks fail, an `AggregateException` is raised.

**It is not the same as 3 consecutive `await`**. With consecutive await, if the first task fails, the following task will not be awaited and their exception will be unobserved. Even if you catch that first exception, other exception can be raised later and crash your program. You would need 3 different try/catch blocks.

Note: now the unobserved exception won't crash your program, [read for more info](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5/) after the code example with 2 consecutive await. It's well explained.

> To make it easier for developers to write asynchronous code based on
>   Tasks, .NET 4.5 changes the default exception behavior for unobserved
>   exceptions.  While unobserved exceptions will still cause the
>   UnobservedTaskException event to be raised (not doing so would be a
>   breaking change), the process will not crash by default.
>
> [...]
>   Note that this change doesn’t mean developers should be careless about
>   ignoring unhandled exceptions… it just means the runtime is a bit more
>   forgiving than it used to be.

Comment: There no returned value for every tasks seperately

Comment: This does nothing different to the question code. How are the results accessed?

Comment: @fetchsod see my updated answer. The first version was really too short, and rightfully deserved a -1

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay it returns an array of given type, int[] if the task are Task<int>

Comment: @GuillaumeSasdy Per the documentation, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.8 `Task.WhenAll` returns a new `Task`. It doesn't return the results of the tasks in an array. You still have to extract them from each task individually using `.Result`.

Comment: @howcheng indeed `Task.WhenAll` returns a task that complete when all have completed; and `await Task.WhenAll` return an array with the results of each completed tasks. I hope to change your mind. Otherwise run the code and you'll be sure.