# How to run many tasks and get their result after all of them ended?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

How can I obtain result(bool) of those Tasks?

```
public static Random rnd = new Random();

static void Main()
{
    var tasks = new Task[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = new Task(async () => await T());
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);

    for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Task {i} result = {tasks[i].?????????}");
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static async Task<bool> T()
{
    await Task.Delay(500);
    return rnd.Next(2) == 1 ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: `new Task()` returns a task that is not started. You normally do not construct a task directly with a constructor. In your case you should have used `tasks[i] = T()`.

Comment: Let me know if that answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59381960/getting-error-on-foo-start-when-using-task-whenall-for-multiple-tasks/59382113#59382113

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make `Main()` method `async` as well and use [`WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.8) instead of [`WaitAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=netframework-4.8). And use just `T()` when assign `Task` to array item, there is no need to do it like that `new Task(async () => await T());`

```cs
static async Task Main()
{
    var tasks = new Task<bool>[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = T();
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Task {i} result = {tasks[i].Result}");
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @GSerg pointed out, making use of the `Task` constructor is considered bad practice across the industry. It's not that there is something inherently wrong with it, it just makes things more complicated than they need to be, for no good reason. If you absolutely need to use this programming technique, here is how you could do it:

```
var tasks = new Task<bool>[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var task = new Task<Task<bool>>(async () => await T());
    task.Start(); // Starts the outer task that creates the inner task
    tasks[i] = await task;
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Task {i} result = {await tasks[i]}");
}
```

Comment: This introduces superflous complexity IMO due to the unnecessary Task<Task<>> wrapping. It looks at the first glance like it starts the tasks sequentially, which it does not.

Comment: @GSerg yeap, the outer tasks are awaited sequentially, while the inner tasks are awaited concurrently. I could be tempted to use this technique if I knew that the creation of the inner tasks was CPU intensive. In other words if there were heavy calculations before the first await inside the `T()` method.

Comment: Then it wouldn't achieve anything, because without a `Task.Run` on your side or in the beginning of `T()` these initial calculations in `T()` would block you anyway.

Comment: @GSerg it will block only if you start the task with [`RunSynchronously`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.runsynchronously). If you start it with [`Start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.start) it will not block, because this method schedules the task for execution to the current `TaskScheduler`.

Comment: I see, they all go to thread pool threads. Well, that's another thing that doesn't jump out at you when reading this code :)

Comment: @GSerg yeap, code like this can be useful if you want to achieve job security by obscurity. :-)