# Stuck at Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray()) while using Task.Start to trigger the tasks

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

We had something like below

```
List<string> uncheckItems = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    uncheckItems.Add($"item {i + 1}");
}

var tasks = uncheckItems.Select(item =>
    new Task(async () => await ProcessItem(item))
);

// Do some preparations

foreach (var task in tasks)
{
    task.Start();
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
Console.WriteLine("=====================================================All finished");
```

It seems to make sense but the program never able to reach the all finished line.
And if I adjust the workflow to run tasks immediately like remove the `task.Start()` loop and change to

```
var tasks = uncheckItems.Select(async item =>
    await ProcessItem(item)
);
```

Then it works.

However, I wonder

1. Why it stucks?
2. Is there any way we can keep the workflow(create tasks without trigger them directly and start them later on) and still able to utilize `WaitAll()`?

Comment: Also probably see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60074261/11683.

Comment: Can you please give more context why do you want to create tasks before starting them?

Comment: @GuruStron Well, it doesn't have to be like that. I was just refactoring some code and accidentally run into this issue. The actual code is quite messy so I was considering the scope of refactoring and it's nice to know here is a way to work it around so if my refactor plan is behind the schedule I will still have something to deliver.

Comment: Why are you using `new Task(...).Start()`?

Comment: The `Task` constructor is not aware of `Task` returning methods.

Comment: The async lambda inside the constructor is `async void`. To fix this you need to change the `new Task(async` to `new Task<Task>(async`. Take a look at this: [C# async task completes before it's finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60659668/c-sharp-async-task-completes-before-its-finished/60664869#60664869).

Comment: [Never use the `Task` constructor.](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is the [lazy enumeration evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/deferred-execution-example), you are starting different tasks than waiting with `Task.WaitAll`. This can be fixed for example with next:

```
var tasks = uncheckItems.Select(item =>
    new Task(async () => await ProcessItem(item))
)
.ToArray();
```

Though it will not achieve your goal (as I understand) of waiting all `ProcessItem` to finish. You can do something like `new Task(() => ProcessItem(item).GetAwaiter().GetResult())` but I think it would be better to change your approach, for example make `ProcessItem` return a "cold" task or using your second snippet and moving tasks creation to the point where they needed to be started.

Comment: It would be better to use `ToArray` rather than `ToList`, so that then the OP can just call `Task.WaitAll(tasks)` instead of calling ToArray at that point.

Comment: That code produces non-started tasks and `Task.WaitAll` will never finish. And, if you start them, they will finish as soon as `ProcessItem` yields.

Comment: @PauloMorgado **That code produces non-started tasks** yes, as the first one in OP's question and is used to explain why/how to "fix" the first OP's question. **they will finish as soon...** yes, that is why everything after the code snippet is written (though wording is not the best, I agree).

Answer (score 2):

You should be next to the world expert in `Task` to be using the constructor. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.-ctor) warns against that:

> This constructor should only be used in advanced scenarios where it is required that the creation and starting of the task is separated.
>
> Rather than calling this constructor, the most common way to instantiate a Task object and launch a task is by calling the static Task.Run(Action) or TaskFactory.StartNew(Action) method.
>
> If a task with no action is needed just for the consumer of an API to have something to await, a TaskCompletionSource should be used.

The `Task` constructor produces a non-started `Task` that will only start when `Task.Start()` is invoked, as you discovered.

The `Task` constructor also receives an `Action` (or `Action<T>`), so the return value is ignored. That means that, after started, the task will end as soon as `async () => await ProcessItem(item)` yields.

What you need is:

```
await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(i => ProcessItem($"item {i + 1}"));
```

Or, if you really have to block:

```
Task
    .WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(i => ProcessItem($"item {i + 1}"))
    .GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```